# how can I select the pictures loaded in windows Form in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some pictures in a database which I retrieve them . To load these pictures, I made a "Tab Control" in Windows Form, which has a "**Tab page1**". when the program runs, a group box, containing a PictureBox (and some other text boxes), will be created for each picture.  my pictures can be load in these picture boxes, and I will have a list of group boxes(**gbList**).  However, I can not select these pictures during the run. Can anybody suggest a solution?

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabPage1.Controls.Clear();

        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < output.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
            pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            SelectablegroupBox gb = new SelectablegroupBox();
            gb.Controls.Add(pic);

            gbList.Add(gb);
```

//to retrieve the images from the database in ProductImages class: (**output** is the result of a query of database)

```
            ProductImages pI = output[i];

                imgbyte = pI.Pic;            
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgbyte))
            {
                Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                pic.Image = img;
            }
```

//to add the group box list o the tabpage:

```
            tabPage1.Controls.Add(gbList[j]);
            gbList[j].Location = new Point(x, y);
            y += gbList[i].Height;
            j++;
              }
```

**here is my problem.** I want the user to be able to select the images (Then I want to save these selected Items). But the "result" is  always empty:

```
var result = from s in gbList
                     where s.Focused ==true
                     select s;

            foreach (var s in result)
        { //save the selected images}
```

As I learned from another post,  I defined SelectablegroupBox" as:

```
class SelectablegroupBox : GroupBox
{
    public SelectablegroupBox()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
        this.TabStop = true;
    }
    
    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Focus();
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }
    
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        if (this.Focused)
        {
            var rc = this.ClientRectangle;
            rc.Inflate(-2, -2);
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pe.Graphics, rc);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What are you targeting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Are you sure they are shown GroupBoxes? Groupboxes are containers and usually do not accept focus nor do they show images..

Comment: I am using windows Form. and I am searching for a way to be able to select the images.

Comment: You wrote that but where are the images loaded? In PictureBoxes? Panels?? Labels??? Other controls? - Also: _"This code does not work"_ is always a bad/useless description! What happens? Compile error? Wrong result? No result? - Also: Only __one__ control (if any) can ever have Focus! There is a big difference between __Focus__ and __Selected__ !!

Comment: Your shown code is simply not enough to see your problem. Try to add more code, from where do you want to select images and where do you want to display them?

Comment: I don't see any code that would 'select' either a groupbox or a picturebox. Norte that `Focus()` only sets the keyboard focus to a control, theryby stealing it from any control that may have had it before. - Why don't you give your class a `Selected` property? - Also do let the user select in a practical manner, eg by clicking instead of merely entering!!

Comment: @Taw now, it is possible for the user to click. but I don't know how I how use (or save his selection)

Comment: Code the MOuseClick event for the PictureBox(es) to switch the Selected property, which may as well go into a PictureBox class (along with a filename string)..

Comment: Minimal class example: `public class SelPBox : PictureBox    {public bool Selected { get; set; } 

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    base.OnPaint(pe);

    if (Selected) pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Orange, 1, 1, Width - 2, Height - 2);
}

protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Selected = !Selected;
    Invalidate();
    base.OnMouseClick(e);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `SelectableGroupBox` is not suitable to let the user select one or more images. There can be at most one focused control in your app - this will be probably a button on your form which the user clicks to save the selected images.
One simple solution would be to use `CheckBox` controls with the [Appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.appearance?view=net-5.0) property set to `Button`. Also, you don't have to layout the images manually, let a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=net-5.0) do the job.
First, add a `FlowLayoutPanel` named `flowLayoutPanel` to your `tabPage2` and set the following Properties:

```
flowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
flowLayoutPanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

Then change the appropriate code in Form2 to:

```
private const int imageWidth = 128;
private const int imageHeight = 128;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    for (int i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
        cb.Size = new Size(imageWidth, imageHeight);
        cb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
        ProductImages pI = output[i];
        //Don't dispose the MemoryStream, the Image class will need it!
        var ms = new MemoryStream(pI.Pic);
        cb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(cb);
    }
}
```

This is how you get your selected pictures:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = flowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked);
    Debug.Print("Selected images: {0}", selected.Count());
    foreach (var item in selected)
    {
        //Save the picture from item.BackgroundImage.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Steeeve. That was a great help!